# Crear una función que reciba un string

Tags: javascript, string, function, operador

Hola estoy programando en JS y necesito crear una función llamada dominio que recibirá un string como "digitalhouse.com.ar" y su función será retornar: "http://www.digitalhouse.com.ar".

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
function dominio ( "digitalhouse.com.ar" )
{
return "http://www."+dominio
}
```

Pero me sale error, no entiendo qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal. Alguien que identifique en que estoy mal, se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Hola @BetaM me sale el siguiente mensaje: Unexpected string                 Pero no sé porqué sale eso.

Comment: Ohh claro, me esta faltando definir la variable con el mensaje. Muchas gracias, así lo haré.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando estas retornando, tenes un error, debido a que estas utilizando el nombre de la funcion en vez de una variable que tampoco tenes declarada.

Te aconsejo que utilices una variable para pasarle el nombre del dominio y luego concatenarla con el resto de la url.

```
function dominio ( nombreDominio )
{
  return "http://www."+nombreDominio;
}

dominio("digitalhouse.com.ar");
```

Comment: muchas gracias, si eso mismo hice declarar la variable. Muchas gracias.